# How to install pykaldi on Mac OS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-venv

I am not certain this question is suitable for this site and if it's not I can take it down but it is about code and I have done hours of research on the topic.

What I am trying to do is install pykaldi from https://github.com/pykaldi/pykaldi into a python virtual environment and then set it up for `Offline ASR using Kaldi Models` speech recognition. There documentation is quite complicated and I'm uncertain as to weather I have installed it correctly. So my question on here is could someone run me through the steps to not only install pykaldi to a python 3.6 virtual environment but also then set it up for the offline asr speech recognition?

EDIT:

So I entered the virtual environment I created when I tried installing PyKaldi originally and ran `pip list`, this was the result...

```
Package    Version
---------- -----------
ninja      1.9.0.post1
numpy      1.17.0
pip        19.2.1
protobuf   3.5.0
PyAudio    0.2.11
pyclif     0.3
pykadi     0.1.2
pyparsing  2.4.2
setuptools 41.0.1
six        1.12.0
wheel      0.33.4
```

So it is telling me pykaldi is installed.  This link is the offline speech recognition program I would like to build... https://github.com/pykaldi/pykaldi#offline-asr-using-kaldi-models. I think at this point I will assume pykaldi is installed and skip to the second part of the above question, could someone please run me through setting up the virtual environment for the offline speech recognition in the Githhub link just above? Thank you.

Comment: it is already mentioned in github if you are installing pykaldi with macOS >= 10.13,  then you should able to install it without much trouble

Comment: so what version your'e using?

Comment: I am running macOS 10.14.5. Thanks everyone for either the helpful edits or the quick responses.